# Does VideoCapture::grab() consume the frame?

Tags: opencv, video-capture, opencv3.0

I have the following code which reads frames from a video file (which has more than four frames).

```
cv::VideoCapture cap("someFile.mp4");
cv::Mat first, fourth;
cap >> first;
cap.grab();
cap.grab();
cap >> fourth;
```

Is it guaranteed that `fourth` contains the file's fourth frame or do you need a `cap.retrieve()` between two `grab` to consume the frame? The [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d8/dfe/classcv_1_1VideoCapture.html#ae38c2a053d39d6b20c9c649e08ff0146) is not explicit about this.

Comment: Read, and `operator >>`: "The methods/functions combine VideoCapture::grab and VideoCapture::retrieve in one call." So 4 grabs, 4 frames.

Comment: @DanMašek Thanks but that does not make clear whether ``retrieve`` consumes the frame or already ``grab``, does it?

Comment: just tested and saw that cap.grab() consumes the frame

Comment: @sturkmen: thanks, that is one big step forward. I again see two problems: **a)** how did you test it, because I see several problems with testability here. I can at least confirm that if you do 100x ``grab()`` you see big jumps in the video. Do you want to post the code as answer? **b)** There are a dozen different VideoCapture implementations so I don't know if they all behave the same - in the very end, the documentation is the only implementation contract

Comment: i tested simply based on observation. you are right "several problems with testability here"

Comment: @)PhilLab Only legitimate cause for b) would be a bug, otherwise it's a terrible abstraction. a) Can be verified for a short video (count frames in editor), a simple image sequence, or a webcam. It also follows the general method of working with a camera. Lastly, there's only one implementation of [`read`, `grab`, and `release`](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/videoio/src/cap.cpp#L603). This then calls the various device implementatations, but the top level flow is consistent. In the worst case double check the rest of the code, it's not that much.

Comment: @)PhilLab http://stackoverflow.com/a/36915719/5294258 interesting. take a look.